# Bash wordlist generator command

Tags: bash, list, generator

I have this command to generate words (only digits) with all combinations of 0-9 for 10 digits each word.

```
echo {0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}
```

The problem is that it uses a huge amount of ram ( i have 16gb) and after a few secs,the terminal dies. I've also tested on my laptop where it printed an error saying

> Out of memory: Kill process 2828 (sh) score 855 or sacrifice child
>
> Killed process 2828 (sh) total-vm:1886948kB, anon-rss:1814596kb, file-rss:612kB

I use fedora 18 64 bit on my desktop (first try) and 32 bit on my laptop.

Any idea?
Thanks :)

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<10000000000 ; i++ )) ; do
    printf '%010d ' $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seq` command.

```
seq -w 1 10000000000
```

> -w option will ensure widths of all numbers is same by padding zeros as necessary.